# How to manage User and Domain in Apache James Server from the Grails Application or Java Application

Tags: java, grails, james

I am using James Server along with a Grails application.

As of now i am manually adding the Domain and User in James Server and I want to automate this process through Grails application so that i don't need to add the Domain and User by executing the command on command prompt for James Server.

I have managed to run the James Server and is able to parse the mail arriving in Inbox of the user registered in James Server from a Grails application and everything is perfect.

I have searched on web and came to know that there is no API to do so the only ways are **CLI** which i am am already doing and the other is **JMX**

I have searched about JMX and the Plugin in Grails but unable to implement it.

Please help me in doing this with JMX or by providing some other measures.

I have came across invoking external process in Groovy but not worked.